# angular get full route

Tags: angular, routes

I have a component at the route "/game" with a funktion on init that checks a few things and makes a navigation to another path.

I want to navigate to "/game/admin" and prevent the navigation that happens within the component at "/game" if the destination url is "/game/admin".

How can I get the information where my destination URL is? `ActivatedRoute` only gives me "/game" and not "/game/admin".

Comment: Get what information? You want to find out the current URL the router is on?

Comment: Yes. But `ActivatedRoute` gives me "/game".

Comment: If you want to prevent navigation to `game/admin` if the user isn't admin you should take a look at `Guard` : https://angular.io/guide/router#preventing-unauthorized-access with the `CanActivate`.

Comment: I want to navigate to "/game/admin". but there is a important check within the component at "/game" that reroutes to a different url normaly. I just want to skip this check if the destination url is "/game/admin"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **router.url**

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
 console.log('url', this.router.url);
 if (this.router.url== '/game/admin') {
   // your logic
 }
}
```

Comment: Great.. Happy coding.. :-)